# How can I get the port number on which the web-service is running?

Tags: java, port, server

How could I get the port number of a webservice? Is there any way I could know on what port number a particular web-app is running?

```
InetAddress iaddress = InetAddress.getByName("email.foobar.com");
String chname = iaddress.getCanonicalHostName();
System.out.println("Canonical host name : " + chname);
String haddress = iaddress.getHostAddress();
System.out.println("Host address : " + haddress);
String hname = iaddress.getHostName();
System.out.println("Host name : " + hname);

// HOW COULD I GET THE PORT NUMBER ON WHICH THIS SERVICE IS RUNNING?
```

Comment: Can you give some more context information? Where is this example code running?

Comment: @NilsH I want to know the port number on which a particular web service is running.

Comment: using java or any program?

Comment: @jgr208 Yes,using java.

Comment: Yes, but where is this code running? Within the web container? The init function? Or the service method processing a web request?

Comment: @NilsH It is running locally on my machine not within a web-container.

Comment: If you provide more information about this web service and how you want to connect to it, we may be able to help you determine the port by some other means.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName()), it doesn't seem like this class cares about the port.  It's only designed to handle functionality relating to the ip address and the host name.

Generally a web service will run on port 80 (default HTTP) or sometimes 8080, etc.  If it's running on a non-standard port, contact whoever runs it and ask.   If they won't tell you, you probably shouldn't be accessing it anyway.

Comment: Is there any other way I could get the port number on which the web-app is running?